# Faster matrix calculation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, math

Is there some faster variant of computing the following matrix (from [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-42266-0_14)), given a nxn matrix M and a n-vector X: [image: G_ij = sqrt(M_ij^2 + ((X_i - X_j)/M_ij)^2 + 2X_i^2 + 2X_j^2)/2]
?

I currently compute it as follows:

```
#M, X are given as numpy arrays
G = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        xi = X[i]
        if i == j:
            G[i,j] = abs(xi)
        else:
            xi2 = xi*xi
            xj = X[j]
            xj2 = xj*xj
            mij = M[i,j]
            mid = (xi2 - xj2)/mij
            top =  mij*mij + mid*mid + 2*xi2 + 2*xj2
            G[i,j] = math.sqrt(top)/2
```

This is very slow, but I suspect there is a nicer "numpythonic" way of doing this instead of looping...

EDIT: While all answers work and are much faster than my naive implementation, I chose the one I benchmarked to be the fastest. Thanks!

Comment: What is the shape of X? is it a vector or a 2D array?

Comment: @Jalo X is a vector, M is a 2D array

Comment: Why didn't you use the formula for all `G[i, j]`? Seems like diagonal is simply assigned to X and lower triangle is not computed.

Comment: @swag2198 the formula is symmetric, so I just need the upper triangular part of the matrix

Comment: have you thought about numba or cython?

Comment: @Moritz yes, but I unfortunately can't use it in this setting. If I were free to use whatever I wanted, I would have done it in C++ anyways.. But the numpy version from the answers is fast enough!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite straightforward actually.

```py
import math
import numpy as np

n = 5
M = np.random.rand(n, n)
X = np.random.rand(n)
```

Your code and result:

```
G = np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        xi = X[i]
        if i == j:
            G[i,j] = abs(xi)
        else:
            xi2 = xi*xi
            xj = X[j]
            xj2 = xj*xj
            mij = M[i,j]
            mid = (xi2 - xj2)/mij
            top =  mij*mij + mid*mid + 2*xi2 + 2*xj2
            G[i,j] = math.sqrt(top)/2
```

```
array([[0.77847813, 5.26334534, 0.8794082 , 0.7785694 , 0.95799072],
       [0.        , 0.15662266, 0.88085031, 0.47955479, 0.99219171],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.87699707, 8.92340836, 1.50053712],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.45608367, 0.95902308],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.95774452]])
```

Using broadcasting:

```
temp = M**2 + ((X[:, None]**2 - X[None, :]**2) / M)**2 + 2 * (X[:, None]**2) + 2 * (X[None, :]**2)
G = np.sqrt(temp) / 2
```

```
array([[0.8284724 , 5.26334534, 0.8794082 , 0.7785694 , 0.95799072],
       [0.89251217, 0.25682736, 0.88085031, 0.47955479, 0.99219171],
       [0.90047282, 1.10306597, 0.95176428, 8.92340836, 1.50053712],
       [0.85131766, 0.47379576, 0.87723514, 0.55013345, 0.95902308],
       [0.9879939 , 1.46462011, 0.99516443, 0.95774481, 1.02135642]])
```

Note that you did not use the formula directly for diagonal elements and only computed for upper triangular region of `G`. I simply implemented the formula to calculate all `G[i, j]`.

**Note:** If diagonal elements of `M` don't matter and they contain some zeros, just add some offset to avoid the `divide by zero` error like:

```py
M[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)] += 1e-5

# Do calculation to get G

# Assign diagonal to X
G[np.arange(n), np.arange(n)] = abs(X)
```

Comment: This looks great, and much faster! But it gives an error if a value of M is zero, which is the case for me for some of the diagonals (that's why I used the if-else clause, sorry for not writing that in the question...)

Comment: Okay, so what is the rule if some `M[i, j]` is zero?

Comment: That is a good question; I believe it doesn't matter as these values will never be used. I just set them to zero in my current code, by using numpy's nan_to_num.

Comment: I added some note to my answer. You can offset the diagonal to do the same calculation, then assign the diagonal of `G` to `X` later if you wish so. This basically gives you the `if i == j` part of your original code.

Answer (score 2):

First, you function is not you equation. As this line

```
 mid = (xi2 - xj2)/mij
```

should be

```
 mid = (xi - xj)/mij
```

Second, I use numpy generate your equation.

Generate test data

```
test_m = np.array(
    [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ]
)
test_x = np.array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

build function

```
def solve(m, x):
    x_size = x.shape[0]
    x = x.reshape(1, -1)
    reshaped_x = x.reshape(-1, 1)
    result = np.sqrt(
        m ** 2
        + ((reshaped_x - x) / m) ** 2
        + 2 * np.repeat(reshaped_x, x_size, axis=1) ** 2
        + 2 * np.repeat(x, x_size, axis=0) ** 2
    ) / 2
    return result
```

run

```
print(solve(test_m, test_x))
```

In fact, the result part could be simpfy like this:

```
    result = np.sqrt(
        m ** 2
        + ((reshaped_x - x) / m) ** 2
        + 2 * reshaped_x ** 2
        + 2 * x ** 2
    ) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with googles colab:

import numba
import numpy as np
import math

```
# your implementation

def bench_1(n):
    #M, X are given as numpy arrays
    G = np.zeros((n,n))
    M = np.random.rand(n, n)
    X = np.random.rand(n)
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            xi = X[i]
            if i == j:
                G[i,j] = abs(xi)
            else:
                xi2 = xi*xi
                xj = X[j]
                xj2 = xj*xj
                mij = M[i,j]
                mid = (xi2 - xj2)/mij
                top =  mij*mij + mid*mid + 2*xi2 + 2*xj2
                G[i,j] = math.sqrt(top)/2
    return G

  %%timeit
  n = 1000
  bench_1(n)

  1 loop, best of 3: 1.61 s per loop
```

Using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to compile the function:

```
@numba.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def bench_2(n):
  #M, X are given as numpy arrays
  G = np.zeros((n,n))
  M = np.random.rand(n, n)
  X = np.random.rand(n)
  for i in range(0,n):
      for j in range(i,n):
          xi = X[i]
          if i == j:
              G[i,j] = abs(xi)
          else:
              xi2 = xi*xi
              xj = X[j]
              xj2 = xj*xj
              mij = M[i,j]
              mid = (xi2 - xj2)/mij
              top =  mij*mij + mid*mid + 2*xi2 + 2*xj2
              G[i,j] = math.sqrt(top)/2
  return G

%%timeit
n = 1000
bench_2(n)

The slowest run took 88.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1 loop, best of 3: 9.8 ms per loop
```